# Permuting a order of items in a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary items

```
[{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}]
```

I want to have an array of "array of dictionaries" with all the maximum permutation order of the list for example for the above array it would be (3 factorial ways)

```
[[{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}],
[{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}],
[{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}],
[{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}],
[{'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}],
[{'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: you can simply do like this: itertools.permutations(v)

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` can do `permutations`

```
#!python2

import itertools

yourlist = [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}]

for seq in itertools.permutations(yourlist):
    print seq

'''
({'y': 0, 'x': 0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1}, {'y': 2, 'x': 2})
({'y': 0, 'x': 0}, {'y': 2, 'x': 2}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1})
({'y': 0, 'x': 1}, {'y': 0, 'x': 0}, {'y': 2, 'x': 2})
({'y': 0, 'x': 1}, {'y': 2, 'x': 2}, {'y': 0, 'x': 0})
({'y': 2, 'x': 2}, {'y': 0, 'x': 0}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1})
({'y': 2, 'x': 2}, {'y': 0, 'x': 1}, {'y': 0, 'x': 0})
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the comments, if you are still messed with how to solve your issue, consider the following.

**Strategy**: Make use of `permutations` from `itertools`which returns a list of tuples in this case. Then, iterating through to convert list of tuples to list of lists to match with your required output.

Here is how you could do:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = [{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}]
>>> [list(elem) for elem in list(itertools.permutations(lst))]
[[{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}], 
[{'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}],
[{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}], 
[{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}], 
[{'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}], 
[{'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 0, 'y': 0}]]
```